# How to render images from the API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, react-redux

I'm using React/Redux for my front-end and AdonisJS as the API side. I have images stored in the API and I need to show them in the front-end side. How can it be done?

Comment: You should provide more context, like how the images are returned from your API.

Comment: The images are stored in the database with the full path to the `public` folder of the API, so in the front-end, the path leads to this path. The default folder is `public`.

Answer (score 0):

Since your API returns full paths to the images, you should be able to set the `src` attribute of an `img` tag to the path of the image returned by your API.

Comment: It doesn't show anything, the images are stored in the API side, and the front-end is another folder. Like this, it points to the path as if there were these folders in the `webapp` folder, while they only exist in `api`. That's how I was taught.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use the URL of the API before the path of the image.